# Python class variable not updating

Tags: python, class, variables, python-2.7

I have a class that is taking in an Id and trying to update the variable current_account but when I print out the details of the current_account it hasn't updated.

Anyone got any ideas for this? New to python so might be doing something stupid that I can't see.

```
class UserData:
    def __init__(self, db_conn=None):
        if None == db_conn:
            raise Exception("DB Connection Required.")

        self.db = db_conn
        self.set_my_account()
        self.set_accounts()
        self.set_current_account()

    def set_current_account(self, account_id=None):
        print account_id
        if None == account_id:
            self.current_account = self.my_account
        else:
            if len(self.accounts) > 0:
                for account in self.accounts:
                    if account['_id'] == account_id:
                        self.current_account = account
                        print self.current_account['_id']
            else:
                raise Exception("No accounts available.")
```

Assume that `set_my_account()` gets a dictionary of account data and that `set_accounts()` get a list of dictionaries of account data.

So when I do the following:

```
user_data = UserData(db_conn=db_conn)
user_data.set_current_account(account_id=account_id)
```

Where `db_conn` is a valid database connection and `account_id` is a valid account id.

I get the following out of the above two lines.

```
None
518a310356c02c0756764b4e
512754cfc1f3d16c25c350b7
```

So the `None` value is from the declaration of the class and then the next two are from the call to `set_current_account()`. The first `id` value is what I'm trying to set. The second `id` value is what was already set from the class `__init__()` method.

Comment: Note that `None == account_id` is hardly idiomatic Python. `None` is a singleton object, use `if account_id is None:` to test for it.

Comment: For the record, your question is about an **instance variable** rather than a class variable, and when defining your own classes you should always inherit from `object`, like this: `class UserData(object):`

Comment: Thanks for the info, will update the class as suggested.

Comment: On-topic, I can't replicate your behavior. When I run your code (modified by setting `my_account` and `accounts` to a simple dict and list of dicts in the initializer), it works as expected. Is there anything else you can tell us about how the code is being used that would help reproduce the problem? Can you provide a full minimal example that displays the incorrect behavior?

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what it was.

The data was being changed else where in the code base. It is now working as expected.

Thanks guys for pointing out the Python centric things that I was doing wrong, good to get it.

Answer (score 3):

There were a lot of redundancies an un-Pythonic constructions. I cleaned up the code to help me understand what you trying to do.

```
class UserData(object):
    def __init__(self, db_conn):
        self.db = db_conn
        self.set_my_account()
        self.set_accounts()
        self.set_current_account()

    def set_current_account(self, account_id=None):
        print account_id
        if account_id is None:
            self.current_account = self.my_account
        else:
            if not self.accounts:
                raise Exception("No accounts available.")

            for account in self.accounts:
                if account['_id'] == account_id:
                   self.current_account = account
                   print self.current_account['_id']

user_data = UserData(db_conn)
user_data.set_current_account(account_id)
```

You used default arguments `(db_conn=None)` when a call without an explicit argument is invalid. Yes, you can now call `__init__(None)` but you could also call `__init__('Nalum')`; you can't protect against everything.

By moving the "No accounts" exception the block fast-fails and you save one level of indention.

The call UserData(db_conn=db_conn) is valid but unecessarily repetitive.

Unfortunately, I still can't figure out what you are trying to accomplish and this is perhaps the largest flaw. Variable names are terribly important for help the reader (which may be the future you) make sense of code. `current_account`, `my_account`, `account_id` and `current_account['_id']` so obscure the intention that you should really consider more distinct, informative names.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my code to reflect the info. I'm coming from a PHP background, so I guess I'm bringing some of that into my code. What I'm trying to do is create an account switcher. So `my_account` is the logged in users account and the `current_account` is what the system reads from so the user can switch accounts. Perhaps there is a better way of doing it. `account_id` is literally an ID of the account we want to switch to.